# Morse Code Python 3: Instead of using multiple if statements for every possible word user can type in, how do I make a loop for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, led, morse-code

I made a raspberry pi morse code program:
How can I simplify the if statements: I want to make it that the program plays whatever the user types in, but I do not know how to do this with multiple if statements. Help please!!
I want the program to be able to play whatever word  the user types in but I do not know how to do that. If i need to assign a variable to every letgter, how do i do that?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from time import sleep


LED_GPIO = 4

print("Getting ready...")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(LED_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)



def lighton(timeon):

    print ("Light On - " , timeon)

    GPIO.output(LED_GPIO, True)
    sleep(timeon)
    GPIO.output(LED_GPIO, False)
    sleep(timeoff)



dashtime = .5
dottime = .25
timeoff = .1

x = 1 

while x > 0:

    let = input("Enter a letter or * to quit")

    if let == "*":
        x=0

    elif let == "s":       
        lighton(dottime)    
        lighton(dottime) 
        lighton(dottime)

    elif let == "o":
        lighton(dashtime)
        lighton(dashtime)
        lighton(dashtime)

    elif let == "sos":

        lighton(s)

        lighton(dashtime)
        lighton(dashtime)
        lighton(dashtime)       

        lighton(dottime)    
        lighton(dottime) 
        lighton(dottime)        

    else: print ("Letter not recognized - try again")


GPIO.cleanup()

print("Bye Bye")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if`, use a dictionary to look up the flash pattern for each character. You can do it in two steps, a dict that converts a letter to morse code and another that knows how to translate that into flash lengths.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO    
from time import sleep

print("Getting ready...")

LED_GPIO = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)    
GPIO.setup(LED_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)

def lighton(timeon):    
    print ("Light On - " , timeon)    
    GPIO.output(LED_GPIO, True)
    sleep(timeon)
    GPIO.output(LED_GPIO, False)
    sleep(timeoff)

# light on/off times
dashtime = .5
dottime = .25
timeoff = .1

# ascii to morse translation
morse_letters = { "S":"...", "O":"---" } # fill in the rest!

# morse to time translation
morse_to_time = { ".":dottime, "-":dashtime }

while True:
    # get a line from the user... and uppercase because morse
    # doesn't do lower
    text = input("Enter text or * to quit").uuper()
    if text == "*":
        break
    # step through each character in text 
    for character in text:
        # get the morse pattern for the character then flash
        # the light for each dash or dot
        for dashdot in morse_letters.get(character, ""):
            lighton(morse_to_time[dashdot])

GPIO.cleanup()

print("Bye Bye")
```

Comment: The code crashes, if the letter is not found in the `morse_letters` dict, because then the call to `morse_to_time` with `""` as input will raise a key error. One easy fix would be to change `morse_to_time[dashdot]` to `morse_to_time.get(dashdot, 0)`. But i'm sure you know that ;)

Comment: @Merlin1896 - no quite. `""` doesn't have any characters in it so the body of the for doesn't run.

Comment: I'm stupid. Sorry. That was pretty obvious. Where is my mind?

Comment: @Merlin1896 - no problem - its always good to consider whether a default should be added.

Comment: i am relatively new. can you explain to me this part please?        
   
for c in let:
        for dashdot in morse_letters.get(c, ""):
            lighton(morse_to_time[dashdot])

Comment: The first loop goes through each character in the user text. The `.get` tries to get the morse pattern for the character. Since "S" is mapped to "...", you'd get 3 dots. "@" doesn't exist in the map, so you just get the empty string. The second loop goes through the dots and dashes and calls lighton.